# how to print a string messages in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, channel

Let's say there is a file demo.js. If I run it like this:

```
$ node demo.js | grep keyword
```

then I can get a string which is returned by demo.js and then use grep to handle it.

My question is how to return the string in demo.js?

Comment: You mean you want the output of the `demo.js` to be served as input to the same `demo.js` ?

Comment: to grep, not to the same demo.js

Comment: did you try `console.log("your message")` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
process.stdout.write
```

I found this is correct.

Comment: And you found `console.log()` wrong ? In fact, `console.log()` internally uses `process.stdout.write` but with little bit of formatting. Also, `stdout.write` will not print a newline automatically, so .. you cant "really" use `process.stdout.write` to work with `grep` correctly (unless you add `\n` yourself, which will be a complete waste)

Answer (score 0):

To print a string in a `NodeJs` application simply use `console.log()`

**Example** :

`console.log("This is the message");`